# how to plot given the equation with 2 unknowns

Tags: matlab, plot, solver

How do i plot a I-V graph given the following step size of V. 
the following equation:

%Given:
Rs=0.5;
V=0:1.5:35;

I=exp(V+Rs*I)+(V+Rs*I);

Comment: The question doesn't seem to relate to the title?

Comment: thank you for notifying, i have edited it, could you tell me how can i go about plotting this graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the graph, you don't need to solve the equation, you can use `ezplot` to plot implicit equations.

If you need to solve it specifically over that range you can use `fzero` inside a for loop, BUT, I think you don't have your equation right, because it doesn't seem to be defined over that range

Comment: thank you noel! 
btw, i have difficulty plotting it because the equation has 'I' on both sides of the equation. Please explain if there is a way to plot the equation.

Comment: Equation:

I=exp(V+Rs*I)+(V+Rs*I);
how to plot an I vs V graph from V=0:1.5:35; given Rs value of 0.5

Comment: As I told you, you can use `ezplot` to get the plot, http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html you just need to transform your equation to the form f(I,V)=0

Comment: oh you are right, the actual equation is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055747/plotting-of-graph-with-unknown-parameter-containing-exp

please guide, i am still confuse with ezplot

Comment: Can you please tell me which part of `ezplot` is giving you problems?

Comment: This is what i typed:

Vv=0:1.5:35;
ezplot('-Ii+7.5-1.1e-06*exp((Vv+0.3*Ii)/2)+(1.1e-06)-(Vv+0.3*Ii)/271=0');

1) A graph of (y-axis) Vv vs (x-axis) Ii was shown, however i would like it to be Ii vs Vv graph.
2) There was no diagram on the graph.

Comment: Oh, I see, you need to define the plotting range, like `[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax]`, in this case i would recomend `ezplot('your_long_function',[0,35,-10,10])`

Comment: Thanks noel for sharing! However the x and y axis are still opp from what i would like, is there a way to swap the axes?

Comment: Oh yeah, that, ezplot assign them alphabetically, but behaves weirdly when two letters are used, you can change your variable names to V and I, and it should work. Or you can define the order with an anonymus function, like `ezplot(@(I,V)your_long_function_without_apostrophes , [Imin,Imax,Vmin,Vmax])`

Comment: Glad I could help, please set your question as answered so it can be closed