# plotting of graph with unknown parameter containing exp

Tags: matlab, plot, exp

Equation is as shown:

```
Ii=7.5-1.1e-06*exp((Vv+0.3*Ii)/2)+(1.1e-06)-(Vv+0.3*Ii)/271;
```

How can I plot a graph of `Ii` vs `Vv`, given `Vv` with a step size of:

```
Vv=0:1.5:35;
```

Would really appreciate any help thanks

Comment: You need a nonlinear system solver: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html

Comment: Can you explain more how to do it?
I have problem because i would like to plot it over a range of Vv from 0-35 with a step size of 1.5, and I have only one equation.

Comment: For each Vv you need to solve the equation, store the result in a vector and then plot it using the `plot` function. Do you even have the `fsolve` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [solve](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) method:

```
Vv_arr = 0:1.5:35;
res_arr = [];

syms Ii

for Vv=Vv_arr
    sol = solve(7.5-1.1e-06*exp((Vv+0.3*Ii)/2)+(1.1e-06)-(Vv+0.3*Ii)/271 - Ii == 0);
    res = eval(vpa(sol));
    res_arr = [res_arr res];
end

plot(Vv_arr, res_arr, 'LineWidth', 2);
grid on;
xlabel('Vv');
ylabel('Ii');
```

[image: solution for a non-linear equation]